# Find all parent ids that are associated with two distinct child ids in r

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I am trying to find a filtering method in R that can work quickly with large datasets. I have data that has a `Parent_ID`. Each `Parent_ID` can have multiple rows, each with a `Child_ID`.

I have data that I want to find all the `Parent_IDs` that are associated with both `Child_ID = 1` and `Child_ID = 2` like:

```
      parent_id child_id
 [1,]         1        1
 [2,]         1        1
 [3,]         1        2
 [4,]         2        1
 [5,]         2        2
 [6,]         3        3
 [7,]         3        1
 [8,]         3        4
 [9,]         4        4
[10,]         4        2
```

In the above example, it should return `parent_ids 1,2` since those are the two `Parent_IDs` that have both `child_id = 1` and `child_id = 2`.

`parent_id = 3` is not returned because it has `child_id=1` but not `child_id=2`. `parent_id=4` is not returned because it has `child_id=2` but not `child_id=1`.

My current method is to loop through each `parent_id` and then search for the `child_ids` but I'm looking for something faster.

```
# define the child_ids we're looking for
wanted <- c(1,2)
# find the unique parent ids
uniq_parents <- unique(df$parent_id)
# loop through each parent_id
match <- vector()
for(i in 1:length(uniq_parents))
{
  one_parent <- df[df$parent_id == uniq_parents[i],]
  found <- wanted%in%one_parent$child_id
  if(sum(found) == length(wanted))
  {
    match <- c(match,one_parent$parent_id)
  }
}
match <- unique(match)

> match
[1] 1 2
```

Comment: Could you provide some more information on what the large datasets look like? Can we expect ~ 2 or 3 child ids per parent id? One work-in-progress: `which(vapply(split(m, parent.id), \(.) all(c(1L, 2L) %in% .), T, USE.NAMES = F))`

Comment: @Donald Seinen There is no upper bound to the number of child_ids. There are typically 15-50 unique child_ids associated with each parent_id

Comment: does this help?


find_parent_ids = function(child_ids){
  
  lapply(child_ids, function(child_id){
    {unique(df[df$child_id %in% child_id,"parent_id"])}
  }) -> parent_ids

  child_ids[table(unlist(parent_ids)) == length(child_ids)]
}

Comment: It looks like your data is in a matrix, not a data frame. Is that the case? Do you care which we use?

Comment: Data.frame is fine

Comment: I appreciate the small example you've provided, it helps make the problem clear and prototype solutions. But if you care about efficiency, I'd suggest also sharing code to simulate larger data for benchmarking. Any solution will be quick on this small data, but different solutions will scale up differently--the fastest solutions on small data may not be the fastest solutions on large data when it counts.

Comment: @GregorThomas you're absolutely right. I'll have to think of a way to simulate a larger dataset and get back to this post. FWIW, I'm not necessarily after the absolute fastest method, but just something appreciably better than the for() loop I'm using

Comment: I mean, it wouldn't necessarily mirror the structure of your real data, but you could just do something like `n = 1e5; sample_data = data.frame(parent_id = sample(1:(n / 20), size = n, replace = T), child_id = sample(1:(n / 20), size = n, replace = T))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
intersect(df[df$child_id == 1, 'parent_id'], df[df$child_id == 2, 'parent_id'])
```

You want the parent_ids which have both "1" and "2" childs, so the intersection of those which have "1" children and those which have "2" chidlren.

Here's another implementation to generalize it to any number of children:

```
find_parent_ids_for_children <- function(df, child_ids) {
  df <- unique(df)
  df <- df[df$child_id %in% child_ids, , drop = FALSE]
  pids <- rle(sort(df$parent_id))
  
  pids$values[pids$lengths == length(child_ids)]
}

df0 <- data.frame(parent_id=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4), child_id=c(1,1,2,1,2,3,1,4,4,2))

find_parent_ids_for_children(df0, 1:2)
# [1] 1 2

find_parent_ids_for_children(df0, 1:3)
# numeric(0)

find_parent_ids_for_children(df0, 2:3)
# numeric(0)
find_parent_ids_for_children(df0, c(1, 3))
# [1] 3
```

Comment: This seems to work and is concise. As time permits, I'll compare the computation time of the other methods for others who come across this post

Comment: I like this method a lot for its simplicity. Works great when `length(wanted) = 2`, but would be a bit finicky to generalize to more child ids--you'd need to mess with `Reduce`, and it might not be worth it (not sure if that's part of OP's use-case).

Comment: @GregorThomas just addressed your comment

Comment: @coolhand just did a quick test on matrix with 1 million rows (repeating the sample data in your post 100k times), my initial comment runs about 20x faster than the generalized version above does on a data.frame, but the `intersect` approach outperforms it on a 2-child case by ~10x. Small nuances can influence the performance, and more optimized approaches can be suggested if more criteria are known.

Comment: I did a similar test on 100k rows with a large number of groups. The `intersect` method is blazing fast at .3 milliseconds and memory efficient too. The `dplyr` solutions in Em's and my answers are at about 13 milliseconds, then the rle method took 54, and surprising me `data.table` was by far the slowest at 215ms.

Answer (score 1):

I will also add an answer in dplyr, which is great for filtering etc.

```
# create data frame
dat <- data.frame(parent_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4), child_id = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 2))

# filter the table for the criteria you presented
result_parents <- dat %>%
  group_by(parent_id) %>%
  filter(any(child_id == 1) & any(child_id == 2))
    
# if you really only want the parent_id which match your criteria          
unique(result_parents$parent_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are `data.table` and `dplyr` solutions. I'll be interested to see how they perform on larger data.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(parent_id) %>%
  filter(all(wanted %in% child_id)) %>%
  summarize(cur_group()) %>%
  pull(parent_id)
```

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(df)
setkey(dt, parent_id)
dt[, .SD[all(wanted %in% child_id), ], by = parent_id][, .I[1], by = parent_id]$parent_id
```

Using this sample data:

```
df = read.table(text = '     parent_id child_id
 [1,]         1        1
 [2,]         1        1
 [3,]         1        2
 [4,]         2        1
 [5,]         2        2
 [6,]         3        3
 [7,]         3        1
 [8,]         3        4
 [9,]         4        4
[10,]         4        2', header =T)

wanted <- c(1,2)
```

---

### benchmarking

I ran a bench mark, which I found quite surprising. If you've jsut got 2 child IDs in `wanted`, the `intersect` method is by far the fastest, most memory efficient, and simplest code.

```
# A tibble: 5 × 13
  expression       min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>      <dbl>
1 intersect      0.333   0.373   1418.      1.54MB    27.7    716    14       505.
2 dplyr_em      12.3    12.8       74.2      3.1MB    11.7     38     6       512.
3 dplyr_gregor  12.7    13.2       65.3     5.05MB     9.89    33     5       505.
4 rle           46.1    54.4       18.6     9.87MB    13.0     10     7       538.
5 data.table   213.    215.         4.64   83.26MB    10.8      3     7       647.
# … with 4 more variables: result <list>, memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>
```

Benchmarking code:

```
set.seed(47)
n = 1e5
df = data.frame(parent_id = sample(1:(n / 20), size = n, replace = T), child_id = sample(1:(n / 500), size = n, replace = T))
df = arrange(df, parent_id, child_id) 

wanted = c(1, 2)

dt = as.data.table(df)
setkey(dt, parent_id)
dt[, .SD[all(wanted %in% child_id), ], by = parent_id][, .I[1], by = parent_id]$parent_id

find_parent_ids_for_children <- function(df, child_ids) {
  df <- unique(df)
  df <- df[df$child_id %in% child_ids, , drop = FALSE]
  pids <- rle(sort(df$parent_id))
  
  pids$values[pids$lengths == length(child_ids)]
}


bench::mark(
  intersect = intersect(df[df$child_id == wanted[1], 'parent_id'], df[df$child_id == wanted[2], 'parent_id']),
  rle = find_parent_ids_for_children(df, wanted),
  dplyr_gregor = {
    df %>%
      group_by(parent_id) %>%
      filter(all(wanted %in% child_id)) %>%
      pull(parent_id) %>%
      unique()
  },
  data.table = dt[, .SD[all(wanted %in% child_id), ], by = parent_id][, .I[1], by = parent_id]$parent_id,
  dplyr_em = {
    df %>%
      group_by(parent_id) %>%
      filter(any(child_id == wanted[1]) & any(child_id == wanted[2])) %>%
      pull(parent_id) %>%
      unique()
  },
  time_unit = "ms"
) %>% arrange(median)
```